# What are some ways to update symlinks when the dir they point to are changed?

Tags: symlink

When the dir pointed by a symlink changes its name or ancestral dir(s), the symlink will not work. This happens often. Is there some more or less automatic way to make a symlink keep track of that?

I use symlinks to organize my directories. One topic is represented as a directory. A topic can have several subtopics, in the sense that a directory can have several subdirs. My topics are constantly under reorganization, so I often rename dirs, and change ancestral dirs.

Comment: No as the target doesn't know which symlinks point to it

Comment: What would do to maintain the sanity?

Comment: Stop symlinking directories and start `--bind` mounting them. You can maintain the entire tree in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @mikeserv Thank you. That seems to be a solution. Does `mount --bind` become not working if I change the mounted dir's ancestral dirs or its names? Is it different from hard links? How does it work? Feel free to post a reply. I always upvote replies.

Comment: it depends exactly what you need/want. It sounds like there is a bigger issue here at play, like about deployments, configuration management etc. Maybe write a small application which does what you want

Comment: @Ulrich: Organize my directories. one topic is represented as a directory. A topic can have several subtopics, in the sense that a directory can have several subdirs. My topics are constantly under reorganization, so i often rename dirs, and change ancestral dirs.

Comment: maybe have a look at http://tagstore.org/ anyway you should probably think about writing a software helping you manage your data. you could also look into knowledge management systems or document management systems…

Comment: @Tim - the kernel has a means of handling all sorts of different `mount`s - such as `private` *(the regular kind)*, `shared`, `bind`, and `slave`. When deployed correctly, they can *completely* surmount any need for links of any kind. You can `--bind` mount a file over another file, for instance, and you can assign a mount to a *namespace* - like one process will see a mount tree in one way, while another will see it in another. These are fully filesystem independent. You'll want to do some googling if interested. Try `echo hey >txt.file; sudo mount --bind /dev/null ./txt.file; cat ./txt.file`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep tracking of symbolic links?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/keep-tracking-of-symbolic-links)

Comment: @mikeserv - Is your comment on the bind mounting not a worthwhile answer?  The possible duplicate Sparhawk mentioned is a similar question, but the answer to that one doesn't mention bind mounting, therefore there's definitely value in keeping this one open.  I've now had to Google shared and slave mounting :-)

Comment: @garethTheRed - yes. I maybe could... but it is a [pretty deep](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) subject and I don't relish the idea. I might do anyway. In the meantime, if you get to playing with it, don't forget the `unbindable` mount type *(as I did above)* or you'll wind up with infinitely recursing mount trees.

Comment: @Tim - I guess I didn't answer that - no, a bind-mounted tree has nothing to do with file/dirnames at all. It is completely atomic and is rooted in the kernel's VFS - which is the filesystem upon which all linux filesystems must base themselves upon. So changing a a directory name or even moving it elsewhere either links through as expected for the bind/shared types, or is not propagated as expected for the private/slave mounts. There's an internal hierarchy that can be atomically affected via mounts in ways that can only be emulated otherwise - it's all kernel space.